# How to Activate a Mount of a Remote Share When Its Machine Connects?

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, systemd-mount, socket-activation

How can one activate a mount of a remote SMB share when the remote machine connects?

This is more about discerning a local event triggered by the connection of a particular remote machine, than it is about the action taken on that event.  What can be determined is the port and protocol, of course, probably the source IP, and perhaps its MAC.

To illustrate, imagine two Windows laptops named Blue and Green, each with a share named Data, that occasionally connect to a Linux Samba server named Martini.  The objective is for Martini to mount \Blue\Data to /srv/blue (or wherever)(and do other things) when Blue connects, and mount \Green\Data to /srv/green (or wherever)(and do other things) when Green connects.

Perhaps I'm too deep in the weeds but this seems harder than it looks.

It's straightforward to mount a remote share when localhost connects to it, *e.g.*, when Martini boots, does its thing, finds Blue and Green running, and mounts their shares.

I even have figured out how to activate a host mount of a share on a virtual machine when it fires up (create a systemd.path unit that monitors the VM's log file, then x-systemd.requires=foo.path in fstab).

For a fully remote machine, however, I'm drawing a blank.  There is a roundabout / Rube Goldberg way via the iptables LOG target and rsyslog (directly or via a systemd.path unit) but that has too many moving pieces and seems like a kludge.  The hope is that something more direct exists.

Socket activation can mind a port but (and I easily could be wrong) isn't obviously capable of discerning the connecting machine.  Udev activation seems focused only on localhost's hardware.  I haven't figured out a client-wise /dev, /proc, or other path to inspect, although I easily could have missed something.  Perhaps there is something in /etc/samba/smb.conf.

Pending further tail-chasing, I thought I'd post to see what ideas the community might have.  Any input would be most appreciated.

Comment: The problem with mounting the laptop's disk shares to the server is that there is very little notice on the laptop that something is going on in the background. If the user suddenly closes the laptop's lid and unplugs the network cable/walks out of WiFi range, you'd have to deal with the broken connection and possibly incomplete files server-side. This sounds like a [possible XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/): what kind of *other things* are the reason for this entire operation?

Comment: @telcoM, thanks but no, this isn't an XY problem.  The problem is exactly as stated.  Your hypothetical possibly incomplete files case presumes file transfer; also presumes laptops; also see man rsync; also "possibly" here grades as probability < 4% and consequence zero (again, see man rsync).  Besides, the event is actually far more relevant than the action.

Comment: I had to presume something because your question was so evasive of usable facts. If Blue and Green are always present in the network, then what is the occasional parent event that causes them to connect to Martini? If **that** event is more amenable to attaching automation to, you could just have it e.g. run a single command on Martini over key-authenticated SSH to trigger the **things** on Martini, and then use a regular automounter on Martini to mount the shares on demand and have them automatically unmount when the **things** are done and the share has been unused for enough time.

Comment: The question was hardly evasive and was effusively filled with facts and I really don't need that kind of attitude.  I'm asking a very narrow, specific, focused question about identifying a local event triggered by a specific remote machine's connection.  If you don't know of such an event, that's ok.  I appreciate your offers to re-engineer the task but that isn't what I'm asking.

Comment: What does it mean for the Windows system to "connect"? Mount a network share, browse to a web page, log into a user account through ssh, ping the remote system, or something else? It's not being evasive when some terms are ill-defined.

Comment: @doneal24, "connection" means what is described in the OP, viz. the Windows machine authenticates to the Samba server described in the OP and mounts a share thereon.  I believe this to be well defined but to be even more specific, TCP/445, SMB3, NTLMv2.

Comment: I've read the post multiple times. You never explicitly said the connection was when Blue mounted a Samba share from Martini. This is unclear enough that two different people have asked for details. Since mounting a samba share does not generate an event noticeable outside the daemon itself you will probably have to monitor the log and take action on new records.

Comment: I did, actually.  "To illustrate, imagine two Windows laptops named Blue and Green, each with a share named Data, that occasionally connect to a Linux Samba server named Martini."  No reason to get snotty.

Comment: "To illustrate, imagine two Windows laptops named Blue and Green, each with a share named Data, that occasionally connect to a Linux Samba server named Martini." - Each laptop shares out a volume. Each laptop connects to a Samba server. If Blue is sharing a path named `Data`, as listed in your post, how does Blue's share "connect" to the Samba server? Martini has to mount the share so what is Blue doing? So far, the people trying to help you have been either having an attitude or being snotty; not the best way to get volunteers to help you.

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps I'm too deep in the weeds but this seems harder than it looks.

You are entirely correct: at the level of the SMB protocol, it is indeed harder than it looks like in the user's perspective!

A single SMB client host may utilize multiple TCP connections in parallel, and if a connection is broken while not actively used (e.g. because of a network error or long time of inactivity), a client may "seamlessly" reconnect when the connection is again needed, while giving the user the appearance that the connection has been active all along.

These, among other things, can make it hard or impossible to do what you are asking by naively parsing Samba's logs.

You might or might not care about this possibility of triggering your **things** possibly multiple times in parallel, or needlessly when the "new connection" is in fact a re-establishment of an existing connection.

To gain access to the necessary protocol details so that you can recognize and avoid these issues, you might have to [write a custom Samba VFS module](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Writing_a_Samba_VFS_Module#The_Life_Cycle_of_a_VFS_Module) that will allow you to hook your **things** to the appropriate protocol events, and maintain the necessary state information to avoid false triggering.

From the document linked above:

> Please note, if your VFS module should only perform connect-time actions on the first connection, and disconnect-time actions on the last disconnect, you should carefully manage that in your module. If you configure multiple shares to use your VFS module you should be aware that your connect and disconnect functions will be called once for each such share that the user connects to.
>
> Similarly, since Samba uses a fork model, where each client gets a separate smbd, your connect function will be called in each smbd for each share that uses the module that clients connect to.

A suggestion to start a Samba VFS module programming project to suit your needs is probably not what you were looking for, but based on your stated requirements, I know of no other solution that could be called even somewhat reliable.

I would be wary of the idea of parsing the Samba logs to trigger your **things**: depending on various details, you might need to increase the Samba loglevel so high to get the events suitable for your purposes, that the volume of resulting logs may force you to trade one problem for another.

I trust you now understand why I tried to "turn every stone" to seek the possibilities for alternative approaches.